# Video Array in iOS 5 and using MPMoviePlayerController possible?

Tags: arrays, ipad, video, ios5

I am trying to implement a set of videos ont his app I am developing, but since I am not an experienced developer I came here to as the help of others.

Well, the app is a simple PS3 games database for iPad using splitView. On the Master I have a tableview with the titles and on the details I have the game cover and two buttons: one for the info on the game (that loads another view) and the other one to load a demo video of the respective game.

As you might know, I created an array to store the name of the games, the filename of the cover image and the description.

So, when I click on the master row for, example Assassin´s Creed II, on the detail view will show the corresponding cover and clicking the info button will show me a brief description of the game.

But the problem is that I don´t know how I can add the video the same way I did with the image..

I managed to play the video using the MPMoviePLayerController, but I had to specify the video, but since I am working with storyboard, and working with just the header and implementation files of the master and detail, as far as I know (or I don´t know at all) I can´t use MPMoviePLayerController class to every video.

So, I ask, is it possible to create a video array and work the same way I did with the cover images???

Thank you in advance,
Marco Almeida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

```
NSString *nomeArquivo = [atualJogo movie];
NSString *Arquivo     = [nomeArquivo stringByDeletingPathExtension];
NSString *extension    = [nomeArquivo pathExtension];
[video loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:Arquivo ofType:extension]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this?

```
myVideos = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"myvideo_01"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"myvideo_02"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"myvideo_03"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"myvideo_04"],
            [UIImage imageNamed:@"myvideo_05"],
            nil];
```

Comment: Well, I think that it´s like Noah said because movies are played through the MPMoviePlayerController class that requires that I specify the name of the video file and its extension, and the suggestion by Fred doesn´t work..